# array element has incomplete type

Tags: c, lua

I'm trying to figure out why I can't compile enlightenment e17 window manager package ejde on Mac OSX.  Make gives me the following output (long lines split for legibility):

```
libtool: compile:  gcc -std=gnu99 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I. \
-I../.. -I../../src/bin -I../../src/lib \
-DPACKAGE_BIN_DIR=\"/usr/local/bin\" \
-DPACKAGE_LIB_DIR=\"/usr/local/lib\" \
-DPACKAGE_DATA_DIR=\"/usr/local/share/edje\" \
-I/usr/local/include/eina-1 -I/usr/local/include/eina-1/eina \
-I/usr/local/include/eet-1 -I/usr/local/include/evas-1 \
-I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/include \
-I/usr/local/include/ecore-1 -I/usr/local/include/embryo-1 \
-I/usr/local/include/ecore-1 -I/usr/local/include/eina-1 \
-I/usr/local/include/eina-1/eina -I/usr/local/include/evas-1 \
-I/usr/local/include/eet-1 -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 \
-I/usr/local/include \
-g -O2 -MT edje_lua2.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/edje_lua2.Tpo \
-c edje_lua2.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o

.libs/edje_lua2.o edje_lua2.c:183: error: array type has incomplete element type

edje_lua2.c:638: error: array type has incomplete element
type edje_lua2.c: In function '_elua_messagesend':
```

line 183:

```
static const struct luaL_reg _elua_edje_gc_funcs [] =
{
     {"__gc", _elua_obj_gc}, // garbage collector func for edje objects

     {NULL, NULL} // end
};
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I guess it's not compiling because lua-5.2 doesn't have this:

```
#define luaL_reg      luaL_Reg
```

http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2011-07/msg00708.html

For what its worth using E17 on Mac is a fool's errand

Comment: If that is indeed the problem, try using Lua 5.1 to build ejde, or whatever version of Lua that ejde uses.

Answer (score 1):

Check the structure type `struct luaL_reg` is declared before your declaration of the `_elua_edje_gc_funcs` object.

You probably miss the relevant header file: either because it is not included, not present in your system or the correct `-I` path is missing.